# Reading a continous hex file in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a continuous hex file such as 0000 ffff 0000 ffff acac 0000 ffff 000
and I need to assign the value read to tb_b = data[15:8]
tb_a = data[7:0]

Code:

```
initial
  begin
    while(cond) begin
      $readmemh("test.txt",f_data,0, 2**32);
      tb_b = data[15:8];
      tb_a = data[7:0];
...
end
```

Can someone please let me know how I can accomplish this.

Many thanks

Comment: Code:
       initial
         begin
                     reg[31:0] temp;  reg [31:0]  f_data [0:2**32];      
       while(cond) begin
           $readmemh("test.txt",f_data,0, 2**32);
           temp = {>>32{f_data}}; tb_b = temp[15:8];
            tb_a = temp[7:0];
........
end;
But I am getting into lots of problem.Saying out f_data out of bound etc can't assign unpacked to packed type etc
I am basically getting into packed and unpacked array problems and also I get "Too many data words read on line 1 of file "test_data.txt" (Current address [-1], address range [0]) . Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `$fscanf` instead.

```
int file, status;

initial
  begin
    file = $fopen("test.txt","r");
    if (file == 0) $error("text.txt not opened");
    while(cond) begin
      status = $fscanf(file,"%h",data);
      tb_b = data[15:8];
      tb_a = data[7:0];
...
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help. It looks that it is working(need to still test it completely). BTW just wanted to know if I could have also used $gets(line,fd) and then sscanf(line,"%h"",data) instead in this situation.... Is $readmemh  not needed to do this?  Many thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, you could $gets. You could use $readmem as well, but you would have to read the entire file at once into an array, and then apply iterate through the array. It depends on how much data you have to read in. Please accept this answer if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Dave,   Thanks very much for your help. Really appreciated. It does indeed work for me. You can close this if you wish